# I need an API to retrieve music lyrics with their timestamp

Tags: api, music, lyrics

I'm trying to create a video for an album I love, with the music playing along with the lyrics. Where can I find a good API to do that ? I've had a look at Musicxmatch and Genius, but haven't found the way to get timestamped lyrics.

Answer (score 1):

After much searching on my own, I found https://textyl.co/ which returns timestamp lyrics to songs. The API documentation for it isn't great and it occasionally can't find lyrics or returns the wrong ones, but it does the job and it's free with no API signup needed.